# MYSQL: Obtaining distinct values in column A having all same value in column B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having-clause

I have the below table, with two columns:

```
ID VALUE
1  false
1  true
2  false
2  true
2  false
3  false
3  false
4  false
4  false
5  true
5  false
```

I need to select all the IDs that have only false value in the VALUE column.
For example, ID 1 has both false and true values. I don't need this row in my result.
In the above example, I only need to select IDs: 3 and 4. These are the only IDs that have just false values in the VALUE column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to solve this, I am doing by the simplest one, after this you may try more.

I am just filtering out IDs with true, and then group on the basis of ID

```
SELECT 
  t.ID 
FROM
  twocol t 
WHERE t.ID NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    ID 
  FROM
    twocol 
  WHERE VALUE = 'true') 
GROUP BY t.`ID` ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You ca use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having max(value) = 'false'
```

Rationale: `'true'` is greater than `'false'`, so `max(value) = 'false'` ensures that there is no `'true'` value in the group.

Comment: It works perfect. It was just I needed. Thanks a lot!